# Set "android:text" value from function/method

Tags: java, android, mobile

Theoretically implementation of multi culture stored in remote DB.

In Android we have the following:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginlabel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/login" />
```

And the `text` is using the value of the property `login` from the file `string.xml`.

Now my question: in the activity xml in the property `android:text` is there any way for me to call a function/method (can it even be from a static class) ?
A place that have some business logic and still returns a string.

I know that I can easily use the following type of code in my activity java file:

```
TextView loginlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginlabel);
loginlabel.setText( GetMyText(R.id.loginlabel) );
```

But I am trying to avoid to write this a "million times" since I have several activities and hundreds of values on my strings.xml.

For adition information, my purpose with this is the following:

- On application start I read all the string.xml and connect to my remote server (which has a DB) and verify if all the strings are inserted in that DB.
- Insert the ones that are missing, with the default value of that property in string.xml.
- Now, in another remote system, the client can dynamically create new cultures and translations of this properties.
- back to the android, I load a list of the current cultures that we have available and also load the values (translations) from the DB. The only thing missing it to "inject" them into the place where I am using the "string" value.

Comment: The [data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) concept in android should be useful for you.

Comment: If you want to work with remote server to load string data. You can get localization files in json from server. Than save it on cd. After get by key you translation for some textview. string.xml is for static case localization if you understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in the past.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setText(yourMethodWithBusinessLogic());
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace your normal textviews with this custom one. Press CTRL+SHFT+R for convenience.

Hope this helps.